# How do I vertically center align every <p> with flex display?

Tags: css, flexbox, center-align

I have a couple of nested elements here and my goal is to  vertically center align every element, and the `p` tags as well, I don't know what I'm missing that the `p` tags inside the `div.item$`s don't align vertically. What might be the solution?

```css
main .content-slider {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 80px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

main .content-slider .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

main .content-slider .wrapper div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

main .content-slider .wrapper div p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.line-break {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nike Official Site. Nike DE</title>
</head>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="images/nike-icon.jpg" rel="shortcut icon">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="content-slider">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="item1">
                    <p>up to 30% off</p>
                    <div class="line-break"></div>
                    <p>it's here: the end of season sale. <a href="#"><span>shop</span></a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="item2">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="item3">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You seem to have some bottom margin in there. Otherwise I'm not seeing an issue.

Comment: Yeap, naughty bootstrap! Tnx.

Answer (score -1):

```css
main .content-slider {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: auto;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

main .content-slider .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main .content-slider .wrapper div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

main .content-slider .wrapper div p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.line-break {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nike Official Site. Nike DE</title>
</head>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="images/nike-icon.jpg" rel="shortcut icon">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="content-slider">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="item1">
                    <p>up to 30% off</p>
                    <div class="line-break"></div>
                    <p>it's here: the end of season sale. <a href="#"><span>shop</span></a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="item2">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="item3">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```